# Bootstrap datepicker month view how to set enddate till of year (December)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Using Bootstrap datepicker to select months only, I want the user to be able to select a month starting form January 2016 till last month of the ***current year***. I was able to restrict selecting future years using `endDate: '0y'` but unfortunately this configuration also stops the user from selecting any future month in the same year which is what is required.

*Example: if we are in March 2017, user should be able to choose any month from January 2016 to December 2017, but with the below configuration he can no longer choose months April 2017 through December 2017*.

Current configuration:

```js
$("#datePicker").datepicker({
  format: "m/yyyy",
  startDate: "1/2016",
  endDate: '0y',
  startView: "months",
  minViewMode: "months",
  maxViewMode: "years"
})
```

I know I can use javascript and call `setEndDate` but thought there might be an easier way using its default option `endDate` with correct parameters in the initial configuration!

Answer (score 2):

As the [`endDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate) docs says:

> Date or String. Default: End of time
>
> The latest date that may be selected; all later dates will be disabled.

`endDate` can be a Date object, you can get the end of current year using `new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31)`.

Here a live example:

```js
var endYear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31);
$("#datePicker").datepicker({
  format: "m/yyyy",
  startDate: "1/2016",
  endDate: endYear,
  startView: "months",
  minViewMode: "months",
  maxViewMode: "years"
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datePicker">
```

Comment: So javascript is the only way not a datepicker option setting like 0Y +2d...etc.?

Comment: @Khaled yes, I think so, `0y` gives the problem you described in the question.